# How to calculate each item amount using rate and quantity and then sum up all the items to calculate subTotal

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux

[items image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFP6Q.png)

Here, in this picture, I have 3 items with description, rate, quantity and amount. Currently, I am storing only description, rate and quantity in redux. Amount is just for displaying. I want to get the sub total of all the items.

```
items.map((item, index) => {
     return{

         <Input
          placeholder="Description"
          value={item && item.description}
          onChange={event => {
            setValuesToRedux(
              `items[${index}].description`,
              event.target.value
            );
          }}
        />
         <Input
          placeholder="0.00"
          value={item && item.rate}
          onChange={event => {
            setValuesToRedux(
              `items[${index}].rate`,
              event.target.value
            );
          }}
        />

         <Input
          placeholder="0"
          value={item && item.quantity}
          onChange={event => {
            setValuesToRedux(
              `items[${index}].quantity`,
              event.target.value
            );
          }}
        />
      <p>{item && item.rate && item.quanity && item.rate * item.quantity}</p>
    }
   }))
```

After getting rate and quantity for all the items, I want to calculate subtotal, I am not getting how to do because we are storing everyting on onChange function.

In redux, I am storing items as:

```
 items: [ {description: "item1", rate: 200, quantity: 1}, 
           {description: "item2", rate: 300, quantity: 1},
           {description: "item3", rate: 400, quantity: 1}
        ]
```

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Can you please share the item structure you are storing in the redux in the question?

Comment: I have edited the question

Answer (score 0):

When you are displaying the price at the end of the row, provide a class to that field.

After that, just get the values of that class and add them in the `onChange` function and display at the end.

Let me know how it goes or anyone has a better idea.

Comment: I did not get you. We use class for adding styles.

Answer (score 0):

I have two options

#### 1. You can store subtotal while adding an item

initial state:

```
const state = {
  items: [],
  subtotal: 0,
}
```

```
//...
switch(type) {
    case ADD_ITEM:{
      return {
        ...state,
        items: [...state.items, payload],
        subtotal: state.subtotal + (payload.rate * payload.quantity)
      }
    }
}
```

Render `subtotal` in the UI, it changes as items change

#### 2. Otherwise, anyway you can calculate the subtotal from the items iteself

I am using `reduce()`

```
//..
render() {
   const subtotal = items.reduce((total, item) => total + item.rate * item.quantity, 0);
   return() {
      //Items
      <p>Subtotal: {subtotal}<p>
   }
}
```

Comment: Second approach is working but if I am displaying subTotal in same component. I have Item component where I have item related fields and ItemCalculation component where I am displaying subtotal value. And these two components I have called in Main component.

Now, I use second approach in ItemCalculation component, in first render, it wont display subtotal value but display on refreshing the page.